# plist.info in flash cs5

Tags: iphone, flash, xcode, ios, plist

Is there any way I can create/edit a plist.info file in flash cs5 while developing for the iPhone?  Where can I find the available plist tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the ActionScript editor in CS5 to write your XML code.  Just save the file as plist.as, and change the file name to plist.info when it is finished.

As for the available tags: Check out [Apple's DTD for PropertyList files](http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd).

(btw I can't help but wonder why Adobe never thought of including a "real" XML editor into Flash CS5... But then again, the IDE is completely horrible to code in, anyway - there has to be some incentive for people to buy Flash/Flex Builder, right?

Answer (score 0):

While your answer to 'available tags' is technically correct, it's only value is to show the limitations of overly general DTD's.

The questioner was looking for this: [List Key Reference: UIKit Keys](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW13)